# android, multiplayer game, device powerful enough to host server and client?

Tags: android, network-programming, nio, multiplayer

Has anyone tried hosting a multiplayer game server on an android device? I'm thinking 1 thread each for server and client (using NIO for both), and probably 1 more for an offloading thread. I'm looking at android devices at API level 10+ or so, meaning they probably have single core ~1ghz processors. Also, only 1 device needs to run the server (perhaps a tablet?)

I've already written almost all the server/client, etc, but I dont want to waste too much time building and testing something that needs computational more power than the phone can deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the needs of the game server. Something like Counterstrike 1.6 should work. Or a Quake Server. Far-Cry definitely not. (Just examples)

You should measure the needs of the Game-Server on normal hardware and then factor in the differences